# 3D Animation with Pop Ups

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, 3d, popup

I have a small issue and I really do not know how to solve it in a easy way.

I would like to develop a 3D animated Hous  using javascript.
I would like to move the house in 360 degrees, but without seeing the bottom ground.
Additionally, there should appear some Pop Ups.
For example, if you move the mouse over a window or the roof, there should appear a message popup, describing the window(or the roof). Its possible to develop it in a easy way ?

Please help

(I already developed a small 3D House which is moving by it self)

html file

```
<script src="./three.js"></script>
<script src="./GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
```

app.js

Variable for the setup

```
  let container;
  let camera;
  let render;
  let scene;
  let house;
```

function init() {
container = document.querySelector('.Haus');

Crate scene

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();

const fov = 35;
const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight
const near = 0.1
const far = 500;
```

Camera setup

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);

camera.position.set(-3,5,30)

const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 3)
scene.add(ambient)

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 20)
light.position.set(10,10,150)
scene.add(light)
```

Renderer

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true})
renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight)
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)

container.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
```

Load Model

that is the 3d House which I am using, at that moment the house is just circulating in 360 degrees

```
let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load('./3d/scene.gltf', function(gltf){
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    house = gltf.scene.children[0];
    renderer.render(scene,camera)
    animate();
})
```

}

```
      function animate () {
     requestAnimationFrame(animate);
     house.rotation.z += 0.005;
     renderer.render(scene,camera)

    }

     init()
```

Comment: what have you coded so far? Please share the code you have developed and what's the point you're stuck at.

Comment: OK I have shared the code I have right know, it is just a 3D house. I do not have the smallest Idea, how to integrate multiple Pop Ups in that

Comment: There are many approaches of how you can achieve the desired results: https://discourse.threejs.org/search?q=annotations

Comment: Can you name me one approache please, my only Idea is doing that by defining the position of the mouse and making a pop up on the right position. But I need a function which always finds the right position

Comment: You can use annotations or a CSS2DRenderer for the tooltip. Both of them will fit your needs but they are very different